# How to get parameter from user front-end in Django generic.ListView?

Tags: python, django, geolocation

I am building an app where users will be able to search nearby locations. For this, I am using this function in my `views.py`:

```
latitude = 23.734413
longitude = 90.4082535

user_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)
class NearbyServices(generic.ListView):
    model = Service
    context_object_name = 'services'
    queryset = Service.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('location', user_location)).order_by('distance')[0:6]
    template_name = 'services/nearby.html'
```

I am currently using a hard-coded user location, but I want to let the users find nearby locations by first getting their location using the HTML5 GeoLocation API. Any help with how I can get their location from the front-end into the listview function would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with any Django class-based view, if you need to customise anything based on request data you need to do it in a method. In this case you should remove the `queryset` attribute and define `get_queryset`:

```
class NearbyServices(generic.ListView):
    model = Service
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'services/nearby.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_location = self.request.however_you_get_the_location
        queryset = Service.objects.annotate(distance=Distance('location', user_location)).order_by('distance')[0:6]
        return queryset
```